# Does losing Vega's claw matter?

Tags: street-fighter-ii

I was playing Ultra Street Fighter 2 on the Switch yesterday, and my friend knocked my claw off when I was Vega! I was KO'd shortly after, so I couldn't tell if it affected anything.

Does losing the claw have any effect on Vega's moves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, according to [Vega's wiki page](http://streetfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Vega), Vega is less powerful without it.

> It takes exactly fourteen blocked hits for Vega to lose his claw. **This reduces his attack range (and sometimes power) significantly, and prevents him from using certain Super Combos.** Since Super Street Fighter II Turbo, Vega is able to retrieve the claw; in Street Fighter Alpha 3, he can lose his mask as well, though the effect is only cosmetic there. In SNK vs. Capcom: SVC Chaos, Vega cannot lose his claw. In the Street Fighter EX series, Vega may reinforce or recover his claw with a Super Combo.

Comment: Ah, I missed that even when I was looking at the same page earlier!

Comment: For the context of SFII, Vega's punch range and damage are decreased. The sound effect of those attacks changes from a slicing sound to a punch impact. His special moves that use the claw have their range and damage decreased, namely Rolling Crystal Flash, Flying Barcelona Attack, and Sky High Claw.